# Get Specific Line From Variable Output

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, sed

I need to get a line from a commands output that is assigned to a bash variable.

```
#Gets the netstat values for the UPD packages
UDP_RAW_VALUE=`netstat -su`

##TRYING THIS BUT TOTALLY FAILED.
echo "$UDP_RAW_VALUE" | sed -n "$2"p
```

I just need to get a specific value from one of the command executions, which is

```
UDP_RAW_VALUE=`netstat -su`
```

The output of this specific command is like this:

```
-bash-4.2$ bash MyBashScript
IcmpMsg:
    InType0: 14464
    InType3: 12682
    InType8: 101
    InType11: 24
    OutType0: 101
    OutType3: 34385
    OutType8: 15840
Udp:
    931752 packets received
    889 packets to unknown port received.
    0 packet receive errors
    1007042 packets sent
    0 receive buffer errors
    0 send buffer errors
    IgnoredMulti: 647095
UdpLite:
IpExt:
    InMcastPkts: 1028470
    InBcastPkts: 552859
    InOctets: 233485843587
    OutOctets: 75548840236
    InMcastOctets: 44792084
    InBcastOctets: 167490770
    InNoECTPkts: 317265390
    InECT0Pkts: 25289
    InCEPkts: 686361
```

Simply, I need to read the **numeric** value of the **931752 packets received** result, *excluding the "packets received"* part. I have tried doing some regular expression. Then found this **sed** which looks promising but I have no idea how to use it, in terms of regular expression. I am pretty sure I need to complete this with regex.

I need the numerical value because I will compare a previous and current value and check if the difference is between the threshold. If not, send the mail.

Comment: As an aside, using all-caps names for your own variable names is bad form. See fourth paragraph of the POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace.

Comment: ("Environment variable names used by the utilities in the Shell and Utilities volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 consist solely of uppercase letters, digits, and the '_' (underscore) from the characters defined in Portable Character Set and do not begin with a digit. [...] *The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications.* Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities.")

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the info mate will pay attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this:

```
 PACKETS_RECEIVED=$(echo "${UDP_RAW_VALUE}" | sed -n 's/^ *\([0-9][0-9]*\) packets received$/\1/p')
```

It will print the content that you saved from the RAW output of the command. the `""` are important or it will print all the output in one line which is not what you want.

The sed command -n says do not print the lines by default.
the `s///p` command tells is to substitute the pattern between the first two `/` `/` with the `\1`, which is the group in the pattern that is between `\(` and `\)`; in our case that would be the number you want.

The `PACKET_RECEIVED=$()` part tells bash to run what is between the `$()` and assign the output to the variable.

Comment: You are a saint! And I actually understood your explanation! Thank you for the help mate! Will accept it as the answer in 3 minutes :)

Comment: I am glad it helped you.. and more importantly very happy you understood what it is doing. :) Sed and awk are awesome tools but they do take a bit of time to get used to.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps another sed solution if you dont mind?

```
UDP_RAW_VALUE=`netstat -su|sed -n '/Udp/{n;s/[^0-9\n]//g;p}'`
```

`/Udp:/` #find all lines that have Udp

`n` # get the next line
delete all all characters leaving you number

`p` #print

**or awk**

```
   UDP_RAW_VALUE=`netstat -su|awk '$0~/Udp:/{getline;print $1}'`
```